# how to make rounded arrow popover in react using tippy.js or react-popper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, popper.js, tippyjs

please help me and it is possible please put the full code of how to use **tippy.js or react-popper** in react to create rounded arrow custom [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjDoQ.jpg)styled popover like this:
and how to use the tippy.js directly in our react application not the Tippy for react But pure tippy